# How to get mouse cursor coordinates on a pyqtgraph widget?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I want to get mouse cursor coordinates on a pyqtgraph widget and send them to a function, whenever I double click on the widget. I looked up how to and could find some similar questions, but I can't still get correct coordinates.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.dockarea import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

def on_double_click_out(event):
    pos = event
    print('clicked', pos)
        
class Plotter():
    def __init__(self):
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.area = DockArea()
        self.win.setCentralWidget(self.area)
        self.win.resize(1000,500)
        self.win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: dockarea')
 
        self.dock_TR = Dock("TR", size=(300,10))  
        self.dock_TR.hideTitleBar()
        
        self.area.addDock(self.dock_TR) 
        
        self.widgetTR = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.widgetTR.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.3)   
        self.dock_TR.addWidget(self.widgetTR)        
        self.win.show()        
            
p = Plotter()
proxy = pg.SignalProxy(p.widgetTR.scene().sigMouseClicked, rateLimit=60, slot=on_double_click_out)
```

When I click(not double click) on widgetTR, I get some coordinates, but they are not relevant to x, y axes. For example, when I click at (1, 1) of the widget, the result is `clicked (<MouseClickEvent (573,-259) button=1>,)` I'd also like to know if I can do this by double clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene.mouseEvents.MouseClickEvent.double() to see, if the MouseClickEvent was a double click.

Are you sure, the coordinates aren't correct? The coordinate system starts with (0,0) in the upper left corner.

Try this code, it works for me:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.dockarea import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import numpy as np

def on_double_click_out(event):
    mouseEvent = event[0]
    mousePoint = mouseEvent.pos()
    if mouseEvent.double():
        print("Double click")
    if p.p1.sceneBoundingRect().contains(mousePoint):        
        print('x=', mousePoint.x(), ' y=', mousePoint.y())
        
class Plotter():
    def __init__(self):
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

        self.win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.win.resize(1000,500)
        self.win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: dockarea')
 
        self.p1 = self.win.addPlot()
        self.win.show()        
            
p = Plotter()
proxy = pg.SignalProxy(p.win.scene().sigMouseClicked, rateLimit=60, slot=on_double_click_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

You can also have a look at pyqtgraph example "crosshair.py".